# Google BigQuery: Export Total Events for one eventAction

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been trying out Google BigQuery with very little SQL skills. Hence, I was hoping you could help me out. I am trying to export data on client ID level (Google Aanalytics term for UNIQUE USER ID) for one specific eventAction. I am looking into getting the total of hits associated with that specific eventAction. However, the query that I have build is probably given me back the total of event hits for ALL EVENTS associated with CLIENTS that had some kind of interaction with the eventAction I am interested in 'search_con'.

I wish to build a query that only gives me back the total amount of hits for the eventLabel WHERE the eventAction EQUALS 'search_con'. I am not interested in any hits that are outside of that scope.

I added an image of the current output from my query. As you can see we have a very large amount of eventHits for the selected eventLabels. This is unexpected. It should prbably be in the 1-20 eventHits range.

Can you help me out?

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel eventLabel,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction eventAction,
  SUM (totals.hits) eventHits
FROM
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([111210586.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-10-10'), TIMESTAMP('2017-10-11')))
WHERE
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'search_con' 
  AND hits.type = 'EVENT'
GROUP BY
  fullVisitorId,
  eventLabel,
  eventAction
ORDER BY
  4 ASC
```

Output: [Google Big Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agcsg.jpg)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your query seems to do what you describe.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for commenting. I added the current output from my query and a description of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel eventLabel,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction eventAction,
  COUNT(1) eventHits
FROM
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([111210586.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-10-10'), TIMESTAMP('2017-10-11')))
WHERE
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'search_con' 
  AND hits.type = 'EVENT'
GROUP BY
  fullVisitorId,
  eventLabel,
  eventAction
ORDER BY 4 ASC
```